# Start-Up script for a running GCE instance

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I just tried to set up a small start-up script for a running GCE instance. I added a custom meta-data with the key `startup-script` and value

`#! /bin/bash
vncserver -geometry 1920x1080`

However, it doesn't seem to be taken into account when I restart the instance. Moreover, trying to execute `sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup` doesn't give any result neither... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the serial console show?

Comment: I found out that HOME is not defined since startup script is launched with root and the access right on the .vnc directory are different. Therefore, I don't think my use-case apply for such startup. I'll do the initial SSH manually to launch the vncserver!